# Applying a UDF to each value used as a range for sumproduct

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a UDF in VBA that takes a parameter and a string and processes them to return a double. I would like to be able to use this formula to process a column of a table for a range in a sumproduct formula and I'm having some issues.

```
Public Function ColorCount(Color As String, ToCount As String)
Dim WordArray() As String
ToCount = Replace(ToCount, " ", "")
WordArray() = Split(ToCount, "}{")
ColorCount = 0
For i = LBound(WordArray) To UBound(WordArray)
    WordArray(i) = Replace(WordArray(i), "{", "")
    WordArray(i) = Replace(WordArray(i), "}", "")
    If UCase(Color) = UCase(WordArray(i)) Then
        ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
    ElseIf UCase(WordArray(i)) Like UCase(Color) & "[/\]*" Or UCase(WordArray(i)) Like "*[/\]" & UCase(Color) Then
        ColorCount = ColorCount + 0.5
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

I have data in a table that I would like to be able to call for a sum product. I've tried something similar to `=sumproduct(Table[Quant],ColorCount("Color", Table[Colors])` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't specified the output of the `Function`. Change the first line to: `Public Function ColorCount(Color As String, ToCount As String) As Double`

Comment: @Jordan - I thought if a specific output was omitted then the output was defaulted to variant (which would cover doubles and anything else).

Comment: I'm curious why hte UDF; wouldn't SEARCH or FIND do the same thing in the SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: @Jeeped From what I can tell Search and find return the place where a pattern first starts but my strings can multiples... for example {B}{B}{G} for color B should return 2 and {B/G}{B}{G} should return 1.5. I was better able to handle this behavior with a UDF than with an extremely complex function.

Comment: OK, so why not do the SUPRODUCT processing in the UDF? It seems like a pretty specific task anyways.

Comment: @Jeeped I attempted to write a function to takes a range and spits out the appropriate values from the function as an array but kept getting type mismatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write all the processing into the UDF. It seems a shame not to take advantage of the superior (compared to SUMPRODUCT) looping available in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function udfColorCount(theColor As String, toCount As Range, toQty As Range)
    Dim c As Integer, i As Integer, colorString As String, colorArray As Variant
    'toCount = Replace(toCount, " ", vbNullString)
    udfColorCount = 0
    For c = 1 To toQty.Cells.Count
        Debug.Print toCount.Cells(c).Value2
        colorString = Replace(toCount.Cells(c).Value2, Chr(32), vbNullString)
        colorArray = Split(Mid(colorString, 2, Len(colorString) - 2), "}{")
        For i = LBound(colorArray) To UBound(colorArray)
            If UCase(theColor) = UCase(colorArray(i)) Then
                udfColorCount = udfColorCount + toQty.Cells(c)
            ElseIf CBool(InStr(1, colorArray(i), theColor, vbTextCompare)) Then
                udfColorCount = udfColorCount + 0.5 * toQty.Cells(c)
            End If
        Next i
    Next c
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly it, thanks for helping a VBA noob out.

Comment: Thank **you** for putting in the original research and showing what you were able to come up with!

Comment: mild follow ups: I'm getting an error if there are empty cells, how would I fix that? also, how easy would if be to only perform the calculations on non hidden cells... I think its just an if statement inside the for c = 1 loop ( if toCount is visible and not empty then...) but I'm struggling with the syntax cell object structure I think.